# jQuery click function not working on second click

Tags: jquery

The title is actually a bit misleading. The actual problem is (as can be [seen here](http://jsbin.com/ivexun/2/edit)):

If you click on one of the list elements, it displays the answer correctly.

If you click on another list element, it still works correctly. But if you expand one element, and click it again to close it, the little arrow to the right of it doesn't change back to facing down.

I don't understand why this is happening, as the jQuery code is meant to change them all back to facing down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Images are blocked, I cannot see them. And there's a warning:`Line 6: }) --- Missing semicolon.` in jQuery code.

Comment: next time please include the code in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the up-class to down-class change is made BEFORE the elements are checked for having the down-class. Whenever you click the element in a 'up' state, it will first be turned down, and then turned up again, because the code thinks it was turned down.

This code should work: http://jsbin.com/udadat/2/edit

It adds a pre-down class, that up-class elements will be set to, and after the 'who's down' check, it will be set from pre-down to down.

Sorry if the answer is a bit messy, and pretty new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: That's done it. Thanks.